# Infer function from 3d plot

Tags: geometry, functions, graphing-functions

So, I'm trying to find the function that produces this plot.
I have all the points available but I'm not sure how can I utilise them to infer the function if I don't even know the form of the function.
***[Here is the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Km7.png)***

[Edit] The dataset is generated by applying the xor operation onto a mxn matrix (e.g. row=2, column=2 maps to 2 xor 2 onto the corresponding matrix) and then getting the sum of the xor generated matrix. I run experiments with random mxn matrices and then I get the sum for each generated matrix.

[Edit]

```
Code that generates the dataset:
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def xor_calc(m,n):
    xor = np.zeros([n,m]).astype(int)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            xor[i][j] = i^j
    row_sum = xor.sum(axis=0)
    return row_sum

row_sums = []
ms = []
ns = []
for i in range(0,1000):
    m = random.randint(1,800)
    n = random.randint(1,800)
    row_sum = xor_calc(m,n)
    row_sums.append(sum(row_sum))
    ms.append(m)
    ns.append(n)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'ms': ms,
        'ns': ns,  
        'row_sums': row_sums,
    })
```

Comment: A plot of measured data is not necessarily or usually fitted by a function you can write down with a formula. If you [edit] the question to tell us where the data come from, and what underlying model you think they represent, we may be able to suggest a way to use your spreadsheet to find the best fit for some particular kind of function.

Comment: Added more info about how the dataset is generated.

Comment: That is much more informative but still not clear. [edit] the question again to show us all the steps in the calculation for some particular examples. It's not even clear to me what the labels on the axes should be. Use mathjax for formatting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Added code that generates the dataset.

Comment: Much better. This might be an answerable question, but not by me. I do wonder why you call this "xor" - on quick reading you seem to be summing some powers. That said, I have nothing more to contribute.

Comment: This is just how xor operation is implemented in python (^). Not to be confused with the power operator (**). Kind of confusing to be honest.

Comment: OK. I learned something. Looking at the picture I would try to fit a _hyperbolic paraboloid_.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something proportional to $n\cdot m\cdot \max(m,n)$. By using the xor operation, you are basically shuffling bits around, without changing the number of ones and zeros. So your sum is on average the number of cells in your matrix ($n\cdot m$) times the average value of your cell, which should be proportional to $\max(m,n)$.

This is not a proof, just an intuition which you can check with python.